Shift (the position of) Table of Contents to the Right
I want to achieve the following as shown in the image:

In words, I want to position the table of contents to the right and fill the left portion of the page with some colour.
\tableofcontents generates a table of contents but everything is centred. I looked into the titlesec package but there doesn't seem to be a way to position the table of contents to the right.
This is also my first time asking questions on this forum please point out any issues there are.
Edit: I only want the table of contents page to have the above layout, other pages  in the document shouldn't be affected.

Welcome! Do you want this (the wide left "margin") to exist only in the table of contents, or in other / all pages of the document? If the document is two-sided and the table of contents continues to a second page, should this be on the left of the second page?. Also, the titlesec is not the right one since, as its name suggests, it is about section titles. You could have a look at the geometry package, at least to set the margins of your document.

Maybe you meant to use the titletoc package, which could help, but I believe that, if you are satisfied with the look of the basic table of contents, it is only a matter of setting appropriate margins. This is why you need to be more specific about the look of the rest of the document.
